# I can't figure out what is making my SSL insecure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My SSL ceritifate is from Cloudflare, it works fine from their end but I get the error that an image on my webpage is being sourced from HTTP, I can't figure out what it is. Would someone be able to identify the element?

P.S I use WHMCS

My domain is:
https://insanesetups.com

Comment: Chrome will tell you right in the developer console. `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://insanesetups.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://insanesetups.com/clients/dologin.php'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
insanesetups.com/:286 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://insanesetups.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://cdn.livechatinc.com/startups/livechat-for-startups@2x.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.` click on the number, takes you there.

Comment: Your SSL is secure. Your *HTTPS Web page* is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading an image from an external site using a non-secure connection. 
http://cdn.livechatinc.com/startups/livechat-for-startups@2x.png

That image is also available under https. So you only need to fix your HTML adding one 's' to that image link and it will be working.

Comment: Maybe you have some cached version that prevents you to see the right info. But now I can see everything correctly.